# Nested Json Object Returns Null When Converting to POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind, objectmapper

I have the below JSON that I'm trying to read into a JSON node and then map to a Java POJO object.

```
{
  "operation": "myoperation",
  "input": {
    "environment": "myEnv",
    "stage": "beta"
  }
}
```

Below is the POJO class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Input {
    private String environment;
    private String stage;

    public String getEnvironment() {
        return apolloEnvironment;
    }

    public String getStage() {
        return stage;
    }
}
```

When I read the above tree using the mapping below, I get `null` for the environment and stage properties.

```
Input myInput = OBJECT_MAPPER.treeToValue(inputJson, Input.class);
System.out.println(myInput.getEnvironment()); //returns null
System.out.println(myInput.getStage()); //returns null
```

I would like to read the environment and stage property values, how can I do this with the above logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Input` object in your JSON is wrapped by another object. So instead of trying to parse the whole Tree as `Input`, you need to obtain the Value mapped to the property `input` and then parse it.

***Note** that setters should be in place in your `Input` class.*

```
String jsonString = """
    {
      "operation": "myoperation",
      "input": {
        "environment": "myEnv",
        "stage": "beta"
      }
    }
    """;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();        
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jsonString).get("input");
    
Input myInput = mapper.treeToValue(node, Input.class);
System.out.println(myInput.getEnvironment());
System.out.println(myInput.getStage());
```

*Output:*

```
myEnv
beta
```

Another option would be to declare another class, wrapping `Input`, let's say `InputWrapper`. The would allow to deserialize the JSON you directly into the `InputWrapper` instance and then access nested `Input` via getter method.

Here's how such wrapper class might look like (Lombok's annotations used for brevity):

```
@Setter
@Getter
public static class InputWrapper {
    private String operation;
    private Input input;
}

@Setter
@Getter
public static class Input {
    private String environment;
    private String stage;
}
```

Parsing logic:

```
String jsonString = """
    {
      "operation": "myoperation",
      "input": {
        "environment": "myEnv",
        "stage": "beta"
      }
    }
    """;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();        

InputWrapper inputWrapper = mapper.readValue(jsonString, InputWrapper.class);
Input myInput = inputWrapper.getInput();
        
System.out.println(myInput.getEnvironment());
System.out.println(myInput.getStage());
```

*Output:*

```
myEnv
beta
```

Comment: Got it, thank you! Is there a way to read that input tree without doing a `.get("input");` ? Perhaps by updating the POJO class somehow to go one layer in? Just to avoid using the propertyName in the code.

Comment: @AnOldSoul Well, you can declare another class, wrapping `Input`, let's say `InputWrapper`. And you'll be able to deserialize the JSON into object with a single line without messing with `JsonNode`s: `InputWrapper inputWrapper = mapper.readValue(json, InputWrapper.class);`. And  then access `Input` instance through a getter.